# Saying "nothing" then "everything", what does it mean?

Tags: dialogue, kingdom-of-heaven

In the movie *Kingdom of Heaven* Bailian of Ibelin asked Saladin, "What is Jerusalem worth?". The latter answered, "nothing" and then he said "everything".

What's the meaning of that?